nekoray can't connect: [Error] app/dns: failed to retrieve response > Post "https://8.8.8.8/dns-query": context deadline exceeded
i get a server from hetzner and i install v2ray so i can change my ip.
i use nekoray in windows 10 for this.
but i reinstall my windows 10 today, after 4 hour installing drivers and default softwares, i turn on nekoray, it worked well in 1 and 2 first time but not anymore.
i can connect to my server through another phone or pc but not in my win 10.
i think one setting in my windows changed because server is okay and my pc has a problem.
do you know where can i reset my connection or internet setting? where is the problem?
thank you.
link screenshot of my nekoray.

i give private and public permission through firewall to nekoray. i don't know which setting is wrong. all vpn softwares on my win10 can't connect.

i found the solution,
i sync and put clock to automatically. and it worked well. thank you all.
